# Python delete one, user selected, line from file

Tags: python, if-statement, file-io, io

I have a text file in the following format:

```
A*
B#
C'
```

My program currently allows the user to add to the file, but not delete. I have the following function, however it appears not to work.

```
delete = input('Enter clue to delete: ')
with open(CLUEFILE,'r')as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open(CLUEFILE,'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        if line != delete or line != delete+'\n':
            f.write(line)
```

The code doesn't produce any errors, however no changes are made to the file! I can't understand how the `if` statement isn't working! Any help if greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of your `if` statement is slightly off. You want to write lines that aren't *either* `delete` or `delete + '\n'`, so you need to use `and` instead of `or`:

```
if line != delete and line != delete+'\n':
```

Even simpler, you could do

```
if line.rstrip() != delete:
```